# Empty list and boolean value

Tags: python, boolean

I understand that I can test if a list is empty like this:

```
l = []
if not l:
    print("empty")
```

But I do not understand why the next code isn't equivalent:

```
if l == False:
    print("empty")
```

Comment: It's very simple. `bool([]) = False ` but `[] != False`

Comment: @julivicoit's not simple if you are new to Python. The key point is that `if not l` is actually implicitly invoking the bool() conversion on `l`.

Comment: @SteveHaigh: U are right. Now i can't edit my comment any more. So sorry for this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`l` itself is `list` type so comparing it with boolean will always return `False`

`not l` is boolean expression so it will return `True` sometimes depending on if `l` is empty or not

```
    >>>l = []
    >>>type(l)
    <type 'list'>
    >>>l == True
    False
    >>>l == False
    False
    >>>
    >>>
    >>> type(not l)
    <type 'bool'>
    >>> (not l) == False
    False
    >>> (not l) == True
    True
```

Comment: So why `0` is different from `[]`? It type is `int` but not `bool`

Comment: why different? `not 0` is also `True`

Comment: `0 == False` return `True`

Comment: I saw the answer in the linked post. That's because bool is subclass of int